# syntax error near unexpected token `done' with 2 files generated

Tags: shell, awk

I am encountering syntax error when I am trying the below code to obtain the 2 output files namely input1,input2 as described below.

```
test.txt   
Q
L
A D
1 10
2 21
3 22
4 5
5 9

while read -r line;  if [[ $line == "A" ]] ||[[ $line == "Q" ]]||[[ $line == "L" ]] ; then awk '$2 < "11" { print $0 }' input1.txt; awk '$2 < "11" { print $1 }' input2.txt; done > test.txt

input1.txt
Q
L
A D
1 10
4 5
5 9
input2.txt
1 
4 
5
```

Comment: `if` needs a corresponding `fi` - also if you are trying to read **from** `test.txt` then your `>` should be `<`

Comment: how to do 'fi' ?

Comment: you may find it easier to debug from a script while learning, rather than jumping straight to composing a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

As per @steeldriver corrections plus one more **only** for syntax, not functionality

```
while read -r line; do      #missing `do`
    if [[ $line == "A" ]] ||[[ $line == "Q" ]]||[[ $line == "L" ]] ; then 
        awk '$2 < "11" { print $0 }' input1.txt
    fi     # the missing fi
    awk '$2 < "11" { print $1 }' input2.txt
done < test.txt     # correct the redirection
```

From your post it seems what you want can be achieved in

```
awk ' NF > 1 && ($2*1) < 11 && ($2*1) > 0 {print $1} ' test.txt
```

and

```
awk ' $1 ~ /^[QLA]/ || ( ($2+0) < 11 && ($2+0) >0 ) {print $0} ' test.txt
```

You need to be aware that checking $2 arithmetically in `awk` when it contains an alphabetic character will resolve to `0`